# Marketing Cloud Email Send Alerts

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-alert

Our team is looking to create an alert based on our automated sends and the amount of bounces accumulated over a certain period of time. Is there any options in terms of having an email alert sent if (EG) a current email send for the day exceed 100 hard bounces?

Thanks in advance!

-N

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using Automation and the Validation function.

Write an SQL statement to get your hard bounces for the day.

The results are stored in the data extension.

In your automation, you will run your SQL statement as the first step and the Validation as the second step. You can set the threshold of your validation to alert you on an email if it breaches.